# Modal jQuery ou Bootstrap que receba e-mail e nome, exibido automaticamente ao carregar a página

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

Tentei o seguinte codigo, mas não está funcionando

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Conteudo
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está chamando o **jquery.min.js** depois do código.

Tente isso:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="CAMINHO_DO_BOOTSTRAP.MIN.JS_AQUI"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Deu certo Luiz! Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Efetua uma chamada jQuery após o carregamento da página, desta forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Não está dando certo.. veja abaixo

Comment: Já possuo os scripts carregados e links tb em includes (Estou utilizando codeigniter

Comment: Com base no código postado abaixo você deverá alterar a div que possui as classes "modal fade" para o id modal (#modal) para que funcione, removendo da primeira div este id. Sugiro que você edite a sua questão colocando o código para que seja corretamente visualizado por outros usuários com a mesma dúvida

Comment: Ok, veja acima , codigo postado

Comment: Rafael, você deve incluir o script do jQuery antes de utilizar suas funções, portanto coloque o script jquery.min.js antes do código para mostrar o modal em javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="#modal">
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
</div>
<style>
$(document).ready(function(){
   **texto em negrito**     $('#modal').modal('show');
});
</style>
```